# server-side validation with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, server-side

I just want to validate some data with nodejs & socket.io server-side.

So I send the data with `socket.emit('validate data', data)`

My approach yet is to do it by sending response server-side back like this...

`socket.emit('validated data', boolean })`

..and get this response on the client-side back like this...

```
socket.on('validated data', function (boolean) {
    validationResponse = boolean;
});
```

This seems very awkward and inefficiente for **just a boolean**.
I think this is an very general question about server - client communication with sockets, so a explaination would be very helpful.

Is there a better solution to get a direct response of booleans or tiny information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was for a shorter or more secure code, but how i suspected with:

> I think this is an very general question about server - client
>   communication

.. was there a mistake in thinking about the communication on my side.
The problem is the security isn't better if you try to protect the application with processes like this, because your client could already fake the returned boolean itself client-side.

So finally i prefer to check it anyway, but if a user send a message with invalid/taken username, the message would not be send to the other clients and the client itself gets an message like `username already taken`.

buddys, sorry & thanks for your answers.
special thanks to @ThiefMaster

Answer (score 0):

What about having a regular expression for validating your field inputs? You could store those regular expressions in an attribute in each element of apply them by an input's class. Trigger those validation checks on events like `change` or `blur` and you are good to go…

```
<input type="text" regex="(a|b)" />

<input type="text" class="regex typeA" />
```

jQuery and other JavaScript libs have nice form validation plugins, but you can create it yourself as well:

```
$('.regex').each(function(el) {
  if ($(el).hasClass('typeA')) {
    // doValidation
  }
});
```

If you have to use your server for checking a user input, there is no way around using WebSockets or AJAX requests for validation. WebSockets produce less data traffic of course…

Comment: "I just want to validate some data with nodejs & socket.io **server-side**." - for some security reasons you **can not trust the user** every time. For no critical validations i already implemented validations with regular expressions :)

Comment: so why are you asking then? sockets or simple ajax calls, you have both answers on the hand. As said sockets create less traffic, [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) is my favorite for using WebSockets…

Comment: @M.Myer Server-side validation that just returns valid/invalid is not better than client-side validation unless it can perform a better validation than the client (e.g. a "username taken?" check). So any validation *before* the actual form submission can be done locally.

Comment: thanks for this fact, very important. so the only solution is to dont allow sending messages if username is taken - in your example ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is no, there isn't really a better (i.e. more susinct) solution in general.  I personally think your code *is* quite short.  If you want shorter code, my only recommendation is to use shorter identifier names.

If your server code performs only one type of operation, you could eliminate your events and simply use `socket.send(data)` with`socket.on("message", fn)` instead of `socket.emit`.